# driver.findelement values are changing every time

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to download the job log from maestro tool. Every time the driver.findelement values are changing. Can some one please help me with solution.

**Example 1)** driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#AjaxTable**11851_t1** > tbody > tr.tvg_table_row_stripe0 > td:nth-child(1) > input[type=checkbox]').click()

**Example 2)** driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#AjaxTable**11859_t1** > tbody > tr.tvg_table_row_stripe0 > td:nth-child(1) > input[type=checkbox]').click()

Comment: Post the actual HTML that you are dealing with, a couple different versions of it since it's changing. Please make sure you indicate clearly which element you are trying to find.

Answer (score 0):

One way to create a single CSS selector would be the below

```
[id^=AjaxTable] > tbody > tr.tvg_table_row_stripe0 > td:nth-child(1) > input[type=checkbox]
```

... but, I can't tell for sure that it will find only the element you want without testing it on the page.